# AWS Amplify defaults cause Google Search Console to get Not Found 404 for page that loads fine

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, google-search-console

My site just started being indexed by Google. It was telling me that a subpage was throwing 404s. When I copy/paste the page into the URL bar, it loads fine. The issue was Amplify defaults for "Rewrites and redirects", which didn't work for my React/Router app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defaults Amplify gave me were 404's for <*> and a regex that redirects non-html pages. I removed the <*> and changed the other one to a 200 instead of 404, and now it works correctly. Screenshots of Amplify (broken and fixed, respectively): [image: Broken Defaults] [image: Working Fix]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Amplify Rewrites and redirect tab, and add the following regex to source address and keep the type 200 Rewrite:

```
</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json|webp|html|xml|webmanifest|mp4)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

It will send all the routes to client side except static files.